# Material UI Slider component error on sliding: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to slide the slider and it throws below error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')

```
    // State to store CibilScoreFilterComponent value
    const [cibilScoreRange, setCibilScoreRange] = useState<number[]>([300, 900]);

    const handleCibilScoreChange = (event: Event, newScoreRange: number | number[]) => {
        setCibilScoreRange(newScoreRange as number[]);
    };

    const CibilScoreFilterComponent = () => {
        return (
            <div className="slider-wrapper">
                <Slider
                    min={300}
                    max={900}
                    value={cibilScoreRange}
                    onChange={handleCibilScoreChange}
                    valueLabelDisplay="on"
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The slider won't slide smoothly. I followed the material UI documentation for using the slider. I am trying to implement a slider to get a range of cibil score.

[Link to material UI documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/#range-slider)

Comment: are you sure the problem is in slider? your code works on my computer

Comment: I cannot pin point exactly what is causing this issue.......the slider just wont slide.
Other then that, if I tap anywhere on the slider line, it set the value perfectly.

the exact log in console when I try to slide it:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')
    at getFingerNewValue (useSlider.js:338:16)
    at useSlider.js:404:9
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (useEventCallback.js:19:11)